# Distinction between open file modes with fanotify

Tags: linux-kernel, fanotify

I find it very very unclear what fanotify flags stand for.
Im using it for access control and would like to identify files opened for read and for write.
Taken from man:

FAN_OPEN_PERM An application wants to open a file or directory.  The reader must write a response that determines whether the permission to open the filesystem object shall be granted.

Is it possible to allow only to read files, without write?

EDIT: I'm well aware of the fact that these can be realized when receiving `FAN_CLOSE_WRITE` and `FAN_CLOSE_NOWRITE`, but I want to make my access decision based on whether a file was opened for reading or for editing